# How to create bottom toolbar (statusbar) in DHTMLX?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtmlx

I've created a toolbar at the top of a cell, but I would like to put it to the bottom. How is it possible?

```
var toolbar = acc2.cells(cell_id).attachToolbar();
```

The constructor of dhtmlXToolbar has 4 constructor parameter [(doc)](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/toolbar__object_constructor.html), there is nothing about it's position:

```
id - {string} id of menu item
text - {string} caption of menu item
img - {string} url of image related to menu item
img_disabled - {string} url which will be used for item in disabled state
```

I've searched a lot, but I have no idea, if it's possible somehow. And if it is, then how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place toolbar to the bottom of the cell, you can use statusbar (`dhtmlxWindows/codebase/ext/dhtmlxwindows_sb.js` should be referrenced)

```
...
var statusBar = acc2.cells(cell_id).attachStatusBar();
statusBar.setText("<div id='toolbarObj' style='width:100%'></div>");
var toolbar = new dhtmlXToolbarObject("toolbarObj");
...
```